# Parity of solution

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

> Let $N_n$ denote the number of ordered $n-$tuples of positive integers
>   $(a_1,a_2,... ,a_n)$ such that $\frac{1}{a_1}+ \frac{1}{a_2}+\cdots + \frac{1}{a_n}=1$. Determine whether $N_{10}$ is even or odd.

The answer provided is "$N_{10}$ is odd".

I tried finding number of solutions and got a wrong answer.Is there a more elegant method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key word here is *ordered*. Suppose you have an unordered solution with $k_1$ copies of one integer, $k_2$ of another, and so on (so $k_1+\cdots+k_r=10$). How many different orderings of that solution are counted? This is $\binom{10}{k_1,\ldots,k_r}$.

There are only two possibilities for this to be odd: $\binom{10}{10}=1$ and $\binom{10}{8,2}=45$. So you only need to count the solutions with ten equal numbers, or with eight of one and two of another; every other unordered solution contributes an even number of ordered solutions to the total.

Comment: Nice explanation!Thanks