# Is the number of ordered $10$-tuples of positive integers $(a_1, a_2, \dots , a_{10})$ such that $1/a_1 + 1/a_2 + \dots + 1/a_{10} = 1$ even or odd?

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

> Is the number of ordered $10$-tuples of positive integers $(a_1, a_2, \dots , a_{10})$ such that $1/a_1 + 1/a_2 + \dots + 1/a_{10} = 1$ even or odd?

I'm reading a solution for this problem and they conclude that

> We may discard any solutions for which $a_1 \ne a_2$, since those come in pairs; so assume $a_1 = a_2$. Similarly, we may assume that $a_3 = a_4, a_5 = a_6, a_7 = a_8, a_9 = a_{10}$. Thus we get the equation $$2/a_1 +2/a_3 +2/a_5 +2/a_7 +2/a_9 = 1.$$

could someone explain this logic with pairing these $a_1 = a_2$ etc? I don't quite understand how they made this conclusion and where it is coming from?

Comment: Since you are only looking to find whether the number of solutions is even or odd, you can discard an even number of solutions and remain with a number of solutions that has the same parity (subtracting an even number from an integer keeps the parity). The number of solutions with $a_1\neq a_2$ is even, because given a solution with $a_1=a$ and $a_2=b$, the solution with $a_2=a$ and $a_1=b$ must also work (therefore causing solutions to come in pairs). So you may discard these solutions (since we only want the parity), and require $a_1=a_2$. The same argument works for the remaining elements.

Comment: Given a finite set $S$ for which we are trying to determine the parity, if we have an $f:S\to S$ such that $f(f(s))=s$ for all $s\in S,$ the parity of $S$ is equal to the parity of $S_0=\{s\in S\mid f(s)=s\}.$ This is because the cases when $f(s)\neq s$ come in pairs. If $f(s)\neq s,$ then $f(f(s))\neq f(s).$

Comment: In our case, $$f(a_1,\dots,a_{10})=(a_2,a_1,a_4,a_3,\dots,a_{10},a_9).$$

Comment: @HappyDay If I understood what you meant if we assume that $(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{10})$ is a solution and $a_1 \ne a_2$, then $(a_2, a_1, \dots, a_{10})$ is also a solution. But couldn't I swap $a_2$ then again with $a_3$?

Comment: @Tenial we could, but that wouldn't help us. We are simply noting that all solutions with $a_1 \neq a_2$ come in pairs, and therefore, we can ignore the solutions of this type by requiring $a_1 =a_2$.

Comment: Just pointing out that this is Putnam 1997 problem A5, and it's also discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2257806/parity-of-solution).